# Angular2: receiving data from php file

Tags: php, angular

So I'm trying to get JSON data from php file but the console shows me this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Unexpected token < in JSON
```

I just sent a simple json array via php like this:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$res = [
    array(
        'title' => 'First task',
        'description' => 'skdfjsdfsdf',
        'done' => false,
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Second task',
        'description' => 'skdfjsdfsdf',
        'done' => false,
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Third task',
        'description' => 'skdfjsdfsdf',
        'done' => false,
    )
];

echo json_encode(array('tasks' => $res));
```

This is the location  of my php file:
[image]

And finaly this is my service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TasksDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getTasks(){
     return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/src/database.php')
     .map(res => {
         console.log(res.json());//--I get the error in this line
         var result = res.json().tasks;
         console.log(result);
         return result;
     });
  }

}
```

I really googled a lot for this problem and tried a lot of solutions but still getting the same error !

Comment: You have to run apache, nginx or something else to serve php.

Comment: I have wamp running !

Comment: I also tried this command "php -S localhost:4200" but angular doesn't work anymore

Comment: Where are you running your WAMP? It's not on the same domain?

Comment: on localhost how can I change it to run on localhost:4200 ?

Comment: When I use WAMP, I let it be under that domain, and keep the php files separate under that domain. This of course becomes a CORS request, but during development it doesn't matter (in my opinion). So I just enable cors on the PHP side.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you, you mean I let my php files under localhost and call it in angular like this "http.get('http://localhost/file.php')" ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @AJT_82 wow nice it worked, but to be honest isn't that not nice for the project's architecture ? I mean your angular files runs on localhost:4200 and php files runs on localhost ?

Comment: That is true. But this is just what I have used during development, because that does not really matter in my opinion, since it's just development. When getting ready to deploy you just build your Angular 2 project and throw the content of the dist folder on your apache server, and thus no longer have the issue :)

Comment: that's a good point, thanks for your time :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WAMP is hosted under a different domain, so it won't work if you try and add the PHP files in your Angular 2 project.

The fast and easy solution is...

You would actually keep the PHP files under that domain (localhost in your case) and make http-requests to those files like: `http://localhost/file.php`. This is of course a cross-domain request, so you need to add the appropriate headers in the PHP-file. From my experience the following has been working:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Of course cross-domain requests are not optimal here, but since this issue is present in development mode, I have not found it to be a problem.

One additional problem that might occur here as well, is that you need to enable CORS in your browser. For that there is a great extension for chrome [**here**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).

Answer (score 0):

You cant serve php directly you need apache server to execute (use xampp) and the src folder is not a public folder you can store mock data to assets folder.

Comment: I have wamp running. I also tried "php -S localhost:4200" but angular is no longer running!

Comment: for wamp or xampp you need to put php files to htdocs folder isn't it ?